# HttpNotFoundResult causes an HttpException to be thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For testing purposes, I have this method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Index");
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

The method is being called ('Index' is outputted). Somehow, it is causing a `HttpException` to be thrown. In my Global.asax file I have an `Application_Error` implementation:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    if (exc is System.Web.HttpException)
    {
        string msg = "UrlReferrer: "
            + Context.Request.UrlReferrer + " UserAgent: " + Context.Request.UserAgent
            + " UserHostAddress: " + Context.Request.UserHostAddress + " UserHostName: "
            + Context.Request.UserHostName;

        ErrorHandler.Error(exc.Message, msg);
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

This method is being called after the system has processed the request for `Index`. I think that the `HttpNotFoundResult` causes the exception to be thrown - or perhaps the exception is thrown for any `ActionResult` with a status code of 404.

This is quite annoying, as it is side-stepping the `OnException` handler on my controller. For my website, `Application_Error` is supposed to be a last-ditch fallback - most normal errors are intended to be handled in other places (by the controllers, or action filters). I only want `Application_Error` to log completely unexpected exceptions, or 404s for things like image or .js files.

Is there a way to stop asp.net from throwing exceptions for programatically generated 404s? Alternatively, is there a way to determine in `Application_Error` if the `HttpException` was caused by a programatically generated 404?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom exception filter that handles 404 exceptions raised by all the actions. You could use `HttpContext.Items` collection to track whether it is a programatically raised 404 or not.

**Custom exception filter**

```
public class NotFoundExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{        
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // ignore if the exception is already handled or not a 404
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 404)
            return;

        filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Add("Programmatic404", true);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

You need to apply `NotFoundExceptionFilter` as a global filter.

**Application_Error event**

```
public static void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;

    // ignore if it is a programatically raised 404
    if(httpContext.Items["Programmatic404"] != null && bool.Parse(httpContext.Items["Programmatic404"].ToString()))
        return;

    // else, Log the exception
}
```

Comment: This is quite a neat idea, and it actually solves a different problem of mine. However, the `HttpException` raised by asp.net does not reach the exception filter. It seems that the exception is thrown from outside the controller. Therefore, this solution doesn't work here.

Comment: @Oliver What you mean by the exception is thrown outside of the controller? I think you are aware of the fact the built-in HandleError doesn't handle http exceptions other than 500.

Comment: I think that, at some point in the asp.net stack, something checks if a response has a status code of 404, and throws a HttpException if this is the case. I think this must happen once the controller has been consumed and discarded, because the `OnException` event does not fire for it. So here, your exception filter does not seem to detect the `HttpException`, as its `OnException` method is not called. However, it will detect a HttpException thrown manually from inside the action method.